# Magic power related to names

Tags: story-identification

I'm afraid all I remember is:

- Magic was based on true names
- The hero was pulled from the real world into another one
- At the climax of the book the hero said his full name linking him in some manner with the goddess of that world.
- I *think* his middle or last name had a prefix like "Mac"
- I *think* the book was written in the 80's, I read it in the early 90's.
- AFAIK It was not part of a series.

Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: Are you able to remember anything else at all? You might want to check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: Thanks!  I thought of a few minor things and edited my post.

Comment: Neverending story? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Neverending_Story#Plot_summary

Comment: The 'true names' part sounds like Le Guin's Earthsea, but I don't think any of the books had heroes from our world.

Comment: Wikipedia has a list of fantasy books, etc., that use the true names idea. You could check it out. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_name#In_popular_culture

Comment: Also TV tropes link http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IKnowYourTrueName (warning tvtropes link()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[A Name to Conjure With](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0380751372)** by Donald Aamodt, 1989.

> An elevator shaft becomes a portal to another world for Sandy MacGregor as a goddess uses mortal pawns to play out a cosmic game of wits against her evil nemesis. Bound by his summoners to a quest for treasure from an evil shrine, Sandy accompanies a greedy wizard into a world where his survival depends on the unknown, uncontrollable power of his magical "name."
>
> Mild-mannered Earthling Sandy MacGregor is conjured to the planet Zarathandra by a scheming sorceror and forced to find and retrieve a legendary treasure--a task made easier, and more comical, by the Zarathandrans' conviction that Sandy is a demon warrior.

Google Books offers a snippet view that hints that 'Sandy MacGregor' isn't the 'full set' of his names.

This is the first book in the [Zarathandra Series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/44648-zarathandra).

Comment: Thats it! Thanks much, for some reason it's been stuck in my head for ages.